# MySQL stored procedure - Problem outputting values

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE `uuu`//

CREATE DEFINER=`auth_tracker`@`%` PROCEDURE `uuu`()
BEGIN

DECLARE a,b CHAR(50);
DECLARE _output TEXT DEFAULT '';

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT attribute_name, value
   FROM user_product_attribute upa, product_attribute pa
  WHERE upa.user_product_id IN

    (  SELECT upa.user_product_id
         FROM user_product_attribute upa, user_product up, product_attribute pa, product p
        WHERE pa.attribute_name = 'username'
          AND pa.product_attribute_id = upa.product_attribute_id
          AND pa.product_id = p.product_id
          AND up.status = 'active'
          AND p.product_name = 'broadband'
          AND upa.value = 'lsolway-dsl' )

    AND upa.product_attribute_id = pa.product_attribute_id;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
  SET _output = CONCAT(_output,a,b);
END LOOP;

SELECT _output;

END//
```

Hi guys, I am trying to get the SP to set the following output.. I cant see where i am going wrong.. Nothing is being returned.. 
The Query itself works fine standalone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery is the reason.. I am only using one cursor for a query that would need two.. Im not even sure subqueries are possible in an SP..

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE an OUT param and stuff the value into that for output.

Also one suggestion, its always good to use @ for your local variables in stored procedures. such as @_output, @a and @b.

Comment: ERROR 1313 (42000): RETURN is only allowed in a FUNCTION
I added the return but it came back with the above error

Comment: Edited my answer. Had not noticed MySQL. For Mysql, you need output parameters

Comment: Thanks for the response however even with output vars set it has the same error.. ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining any [output parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html) as far as I can tell.  That would make it very difficult to get data back from a SQL stored procedure.